# Import products: Replace existing complex data by default

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport

I'm using Import function to import my products on my eCommerce web site. Since i dont need Append complex data function, could it be done, that the function Replace Existing Complex data" is selected by default.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this question, and I just figured out how to do it.

In your Magento directory, create this folder structure:

app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Source/Import

Into this folder copy this module:

app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Source/Import/Behavior.php

Edit the module and move the array entry for BEHAVIOR_REPLACE to the top of the 'return array' statement.